# Deleting a number from an array that is being pointed to?

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm having a hard time with this little project of mine; can someone help me out? I am trying to take a pointer to an array, a number, and remove the number if it is present in the array. If the number is removed, the array shrinks. ***Please note at the time of running removeNumber size = 6.***

```
main
{
int size = 5;  // setting array size
int *a = new int[size]; // allocating dynamic array

// initializing array
a[0] = 0; a[1] = 10; a[2] = 20; a[3] = 30; a[4] = 40;

removeNumber(a, 10, size);
}
```

And now the prototype:

```
void removeNumber(int *& arrayPtr, int number, int &size)
{
    int index = check(arrayPtr, number, size);
    int *newArray = new int[size - 1];

    if (index != -1)
    {
        for (int i = number; i <= size; ++i)
            newArray[i] = *&arrayPtr[i + 1];

        delete[] arrayPtr;

        arrayPtr = newArray;

        size -= 1;
    }
}
```

Check for reference:

```
int check(int *arrayPtr, int number, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (arrayPtr[i] == number) return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Why not making your life easier and use a `std::vector<int>` instead? Reinventing the wheel isn't useful (and mostly error prone).

Comment: @Christian Vokurka  What is the problem?

Comment: The loop `for (int i = number; i <= size; ++i) newArray[i] = *&arrayPtr[i + 1];` will acces *both* arrays out of bounds. (Edit: assuming it would ever run, as in your example you are passing in a `number` that is bigger than `size`)

Answer (score 0):

The function is wrong. First of all it has a memory leak in case when the target value is not found in the array.

```
void removeNumber(int *& arrayPtr, int number, int &size)
{
    int index = check(arrayPtr, number, size);
    int *newArray = new int[size - 1];
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    if (index != -1)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Secondly there is used incorrect range of indices

```
   for (int i = number; i <= size; ++i)
                ^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^
        newArray[i] = *&arrayPtr[i + 1];
                                 ^^^^^^
```

And you could write this expression `*&arrayPtr[i + 1]` simpler just like `arrayPtr[i + 1]`.

You forgot to copy the elements of the original array before the index `index`. `number` is not a valid index.

Also it would be better if the function returned a Boolean value saying whether the operation was successful or not. You can change the size of the array in the calling function if the call was successful.

So I would write the function like

```
bool removeNumber( int * &arrayPtr, int n, int value )
{
    int index = check( arrayPtr, number, size );

    if ( index != -1 )
    {
        int *tmp = new int[size - 1];

        int i = 0;

        for ( ; i < index; ++i ) tmp[i] = arrayPtr[i];
        for ( ; i < size - 1; i++ ) tmp[i] = arrayPtr[i+1];

        delete [] arrayPtr;

        arrayPtr = tmp;
    }

    return index != -1;
}
```

Comment: I think there's a typo: `delete [] tmp;` should be `delete [] arrayPtr;`

Comment: Thank you for the help! I was rather confused and now I think I get it!

Comment: @UnholySheep Thanks. It is a typo.:)

Comment: @ChristianVokurka Take into account that I made a typo in the suggested function implementation that I uodated.:)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
for (int i = number; i <= size; ++i)
```

First of all you start the iteration from the value of the number that you searched(in your case 10) and as a result you will not enter the for loop.So the correct starting value of i is the first number of the array which is 0.Then this line of code here:

```
newArray[i] = *&arrayPtr[i + 1];
```

doesn't even make sense(as a thought process not syntactically), but what i think you want to do here is just copy the correct element from the old array to the new one.

A correct implementation of the previous is the following code:

```
void removeNumber(int *& arrayPtr, int number, int &size)
{
    int index = check(arrayPtr, number, size);
    if (index != -1)
    {
        int *newArray = new int[size - 1];
        int i = 0,j=0; //i for the old array and j for the new
        while(i < size)//while we are in bounds
        {
            if(i==index)//if the index is the index of the given element
            {           //skip this number
                i++;
                continue;
            }
            newArray[j++] = arrayPtr[i++];//copy the correct number to the correct position
        }
        delete[] arrayPtr;

        arrayPtr = newArray;

        size -= 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: @ UnholySheep I forgot that sorry, i updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I appreciate you taking your time to help stupid me over here :P

Comment: @ChristianVokurka I hope my answer  was simple enough to helped you understand your mistake.

Comment: By the way, you shouldn't say that *"`newArray[i] = *&arrayPtr[i + 1];` doesn't even make sense"*, it's just a more complicated way of writing `newArray[i] = arrayPtr[i + 1];` (as explained in Vlad's answer)

Comment: @UnholySheep I mean that this does not help the op accomplish what he wanted to do.Not that it is syntacticly wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It is ok to reinvent the wheel in order to learn. However you should be aware of the standard way to handle this: using `std::vector` along with `std::remove`/`std::remove_if` (defined in `#include <algorithm>`) would make your life much simpler, with the benefit of a performant implementation.

```
void removeNumber(std::vector<int>& vec, int number) {
    vec.erase(std::remove(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec), number),
              std::end(vec));
    // If you really want to shrink the vector, you can call...
    vec.shrink_to_fit();
}
```

I also made a little <kbd>[demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c23f922877fbc681)</kbd> to show you that it works as intended.